# data automatically synchronizing the remote database php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am developing an inventory management web application using `PHP` and `MySQL`. This application will run both locally and remotely. If not connected to the internet, data will be stored in the local database however, when the internet is available, the application will automatically synchronize to the remote database. Does PHP/MySQL support these sort of local and remote capabilities?

Comment: You need to setup MySQL master slave replication, where the Master is your localhost database and Slave remote database

Answer (score 1):

This sort of application is doable using PHP and MySQL. A good solution would be to use `cURL` connections using API Keys or tokens with `jSON` service requests and receipts. This kind of application would be fairly extensive to create. The local machine would obviously need to be running a webservice and have `PHP` and `MySQL` installed.

**Here is the cURL manual:**

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

**Here is some info on jSON:**

http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php